# Мусорные картинки при обновлении имеющейся

Tags: django

Думаю это большая проблема в Django, но панацеи (как я понимаю) нет.

У меня есть модель пользователя с полем `ImageField` для аватарки. Из личного кабинета пользователь меняет аватарку передавая через форму новую картинку. Все хорошо, аватарка изменена и храниться у меня в папке, но старая аватарка(фаил) так же остался в папке!

Есть ли универсальный способ чистить "устаревшие" картинки? Возможно требуется переопределение метода save() когда я сохраняю форму в view? Я не совсем понимаю как это все сделать...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, такая особенность у django действительно имеется - старые картинки не удаляются.

Проблему можно решить несколькими методами

1. Переопределить метод `save`. Суть заключается в том, что нужно получить объект, хранящийся на сервере, проверить различаются ли между ними изображения и удалить старое:

   ```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
           this = MyModelName.objects.get(id=self.id)
           if this.MyImageFieldName != self.MyImageFieldName:
               this.MyImageFieldName.delete()
       except: pass
       super(MyModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
2. Отслеживать сигналы pre_save и post_save соответственно манипулируя удалением из них (сложно)
3. Время от времени проходиться периодической задачей по файлам в папке и всем полям FileField, выискивая и удаляя лишние

Но как по мне лучше всего с этой задачей справляется дополнение [django cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup). Поэтому советую установить его и забыть про эту проблему

Comment: 1.1 Вторая реазлизация переопределение метода с сохранением на основании id пользователя, или каких-то данных из таблицы. Получается что после повторной загрузки картинка перезапишется с тем же названием.

Comment: Если речь идет о забытых картинках, то это не всегда плохо. Каталог товаров. Растаскивают на форумы. Удаляем картинку, вместо нашей рекламы теперь там пустое место. Теряем клиентов. На место картинка не найдена в случае магазинов если освобождаем место нужно отдавать обязательно заглушку.